# Prove what the sum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)-f(n-1)$ is

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)-f(n-1)$

I have three series that look like the above, is there a general way to prove this?

I have one function where $f(n) = \sin \frac{-2}{n}$ and  $f(n+1) = \sin \frac{-2}{n+1}$

I don't know how to go about this any help in the right direction would be great. thanks

Comment: Is f a function of x or n?

Comment: Most likely it's a function of n and OP doesn't understand function notation like most people.

Comment: In your definition $\;f(0)\;$ isn't defined, yet it appears in the first summand...

Comment: The answer is "telescoping series": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series  See the first example under "In general" on that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f(k)-f(k-1)\right)=f(1)-f(0)+f(2)-f(1)+\ldots+f(n)-f(n-1)=$$

$$=f(n)-f(0)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;\ldots$$

Comment: I see what you're saying maybe just to confirm, if the sequence is decreasing then it would converge to -f(1) other wise it could diverge? Thats just what I seem to be getting from the few questions I have that follow the trend I was asking about.

Comment: @capa_matrix, it must be that $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\;$ exists finitely. Nothing about decreasing or increasing. You have here a telescopic series.